# Want to disprove $\exists$ an injection from $(A-B) \rightarrow B.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove (or disprove) $\#(A-B) \leq \#B$.

Can someone please check my work?

---

Want to show $\exists$ a function $j$ such that for some $x_1,x_2 \in (A-B)$, $j(x_1) = j(x_2) \land x_1 \neq x_2$

---

UPDATE #1:

Firstly, consider the case where $\#A < \#B \land A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Choose $A = \emptyset$ and $B = \{1\}$ where $(A-B) = A = \emptyset$.

$\emptyset$ is injective to any set by the empty function $\emptyset$, so it follows that

$\exists$ a function, namely $\emptyset$, that is injective from $(A-B)$ to $B$.

Secondly, consider the case where $\#A > \#B \land A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Choose $A = \{-2,2\}$ and $B = \{4\}$ where $(A-B) = A = \{-2,2\}$

Let $j(x) = x^2$.

$j(-2) = (-2)^2 = 4$.

$j(2) = (2)^2 = 4$.

$4 = 4$, but $-2 \neq 2$.

So $j:(A-B) \rightarrow B$ is not injective.

Through counterexample we see that not all functions from $(A-B)$ to $B$ are injections.

Comment: Try working with counterexamples instead of proving the converse or whatever it is you are actually doing.  What if $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\emptyset$.  What if $A=\emptyset$ and $B=\{1\}$?  The correct conclusion is that sometimes but not always you will have $|A\setminus B|\leq |B|$

Comment: When something is not true, you do *not* have to show it is "always false", but just that it *may* be false under certain circumstances. This is what counter-examples are for. For example, the statement: "All multiples of 3 are even" is false, not because all multiples of 3 are odd, but because SOME multiples of 3 are odd.

Comment: An injection *could* exist depending on your choice of A and B.  You've shown that there are counter examples of A and B where no such injection can exist.  But you haven't shown, and you can't show, that given any A and B no such injection can exist, so you should be careful not to make such a claim.  You inadvertently claimed such and you shouldn't have.  Meanwhile, your counter example should that $j(x) = x^2$ is not an injection.  That doesn't show that *no* function is an injection.

Comment: Consider A={-2,2,3,4,5,6} B ={4,5,6} so A-B = {-2,2,3}.  Let j(x) = x^2.  Then j(x) is not an injection as you pointed out.  But let k:A-B to B and k(-2) = 4, k(2) = 5 and k(3) = 6.  That *is* an injection so you haven't shown an injection *can't* exist.  You only showed there is *one* function that isn't an injection.  But....

Comment: ...Let A = {1,2,3} and B= {3} then j:{1,2} -> {3} can't be an injection. j(1) *has* to equal 3 as that is the only option and j(2) *has* to equal 3 as that is the only option so  $j(1) = j(2) \not \implies 1 =2$ as $1 \ne 2$.  So that is a counter example where an injection can *not* exist.  Actually, if card(A - B) > B an injection is impossible which gets back to the *very* statement to be disproved....

Comment: .... the *EASIEST* counter example is set |A| = a and |B| = b and choose values where a > 2b so a-b > b.  A= {1.... 5000}.  B={1}.  |A-B| =4999 > |B| = 1.

Comment: If I amend my wording to say that I've shown that not all functions from $(A-B) \rightarrow B$ are injections, instead of stating that all functions aren't, is that OK?

Comment: @fleablood I still think the easiest counterexamples lie with one-element sets and zero-element sets, but perhaps that is simply how I was taught.

Comment: I made an edit, can we take another look at this?

Comment: Yes, A - empty set = A has cardinality  greater than the empty set.  It can't get much simpler than that.